# Why my code is reporting error when I add more lines of code in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-bigquery

I'm trying to visualize a dataset in bigquery, but for this dataste I'm getting the same kind of error:

```
SELECT
  Playtime,
  Feedback,
  Review
FROM
  `get-started-with-sql.Hogwarts_legacy_game.reviews`
WHERE
Feedback = 'Positive' AND Playtime != 0
GROUP BY
  Playtime
ORDER BY
  Playtime DESC
```

And it gives this error: SELECT list expression references column Feedback which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:3],

I don't know what's going on, sometimes it says the same for the Playtime, and now it's saying for the Feedback.

I tried to refresh it and retype again with less code:

```
SELECT
  Playtime,
  Feedback,
  Review
FROM
  `get-started-with-sql.Hogwarts_legacy_game.reviews`
WHERE
Feedback = 'Positive'
```

But if I keep adding more line, the error comes

Comment: If you're not aggregating, then remove the GROUP BY or GROUP BY all the columns you are returning.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that teh query is using [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator, so all result columns should be either part of group by condition or some aggregation function, such as [max(), min()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp).

Based on your input query, if you are looking for all positive feedback and reviews sorted by most recent playtime, you need to put (playtime, Feedback, Review) all into group by condition. Here is the query:

```
SELECT Playtime, Feedback, Review 
FROM `get-started-with-sql.Hogwarts_legacy_game.reviews` 
WHERE Feedback = 'Positive' AND Playtime != 0
GROUP BY Playtime, Feedback, Review 
ORDER BY Playtime DESC`
```

On the other hand, if your input data have no duplicated reviews for the same playtime, you probably don't need group by operator at all. in that case. Here is the query:

```
SELECT Playtime, Feedback, Review 
FROM `get-started-with-sql.Hogwarts_legacy_game.reviews` 
WHERE Feedback = 'Positive' AND Playtime != 0
ORDER BY Playtime DESC`
```